# Trying to create an apex page with a specific height

Tags: visualforce, community, visualforce-component, height

I am not new to development but am when it comes to Salesforce Visual Force.

I am trying to create a page that will be a certain height. When this Visual Force page is inserted into the Salesforce Case Record page (Lightning) it is adding in additional white space to the div that I was not expecting (see image below).

How do I fix this? How do you control the height of the page to only give you what you want and nothing else?

**Code:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
<style>
#thePanel {
border: 1px solid red; 
height:120px;
}
</style>
<apex:outputPanel >
<div id="thePanel">
<apex:outputLink value="https://www.salesforce.com" id="theLink">www.salesforce.com</apex:outputLink>
</div>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the [VF and Lightning Experience Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_visualforce)?

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this trail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add your visual force page to the Case Layout, you can specify the height for it (using the spanner that comes up when you hover the upper right corner of the VF within the page layout edit page). Example:
[image]

Comment: I will try it tomorrow. Thanks.